# Remove 1000 rep requirement to edit tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, tags, wiki, editing

I propose that until we're out of beta we eliminate or reduce the requirements to edit tag wikis. Right now nobody even has 1000 rep. Perhaps to get some action there, we can make the requirement something like having asked or answered a question with the tag and have been up-voted once in order to edit tag wikis.

Comment: We now have several people who have the power to edit tag wikis. Further, as Ivo suggests, if you have a suggestion for a tag wiki you can post it here in meta.android.

Answer (score 4):

In a recent change, now virtually anyone can suggest changes to tag wikis.

As with edits to posts, users with insufficient reputation for the full privilege will have their edits reviewed by mods and 10K users.

So get out there and edit those tag wikis!

Answer (score 1):

There <del>are now several people</del> is one lonely guy with 1000+ reputation. (Didn't we get temporary mods?) This is probably no longer necessary.

Comment: I'm currently the only users with 1000+

Comment: I...hmmm...I could have sworn there were more. Okay, well, there's one at least.

Comment: People are getting there.  This restriction probably shouldn't have been in effect during private beta (I noticed a lot of other restrictions were lifted), but I think we'll be fine if we can just wait another few days.

Comment: If users have a proposal for a tag wiki, they can post it on Meta and I'm sure the mods will put it up there.